# React Redux Watson Chatbot State Issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am new to react redux. I am trying to create a watson based chatbot using react and redux. My nodejs backend linked to watson api is working fine. However, I am bit confused in how to handle user and bot messages in front end side?

On component did mount, I dispatch the action to my backend and then I get the response from Watson and state is updated accordingly. First time, I only send an empty string to backend. 
When user press the send message button with his message. Action gets triggered again. I am using redux thunk to do async operation. when I get a response from my backend then, I dispatched that action with type "SEND_USER_MSG_TO_SOE" & payload. Now i have to send previous response which is stored in state + new input text to backend to get new response.

In my reducer, I am doing something like this [...state, action.payload]. Now it is overriding the input value of previous response as well. Could you please explain.

I need input and output message in array. So that I can use map and show it in as list.

Another thing, If I don't return [...state, action.payload] and send only payload. Then I left with only one response. How can I create array out of it with previous response input and output?

I am attaching Picture of Response. Please guide me

[Watson Backend Response Image](https://i.imgur.com/330ewTQ.png)

Thanks 
Meet

```
reducer: 
export default (state = [], action) => {
  console.log('reducer payload ---> ', action.payload);

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SEND_USER_MSG_TO_SOE':
      return [...state, action.payload]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  watsonResponse: converReducer
})
```

```
action:
export const sendMessage = (userInput) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    let response = null;
    if (userInput === undefined) {
      response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8014/message_in', userInput);
    } else {
      let newInput = [...getState().watsonResponse];
      newInput[newInput.length - 1].input.text = userInput;
      response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8014/message_in', newInput[newInput.length - 1]);
    }
    dispatch({
      type: "SEND_USER_MSG_TO_SOE",
      payload: response.data
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is an issue

`newInput[newInput.length - 1].input.text = userInput;`

You are overwriting the last entry in the array with the user input. You probably need to `push` a new item in the array.